# string.split but keeping sequential matches

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I've sifted through many questions but haven't come across one that answered this for me.

```
string input = "~abc~~~123~~~hijkl~9";
string[] postSplit = input.Split('~');
```

The response I see is:

> [0]-""
>
> [1]-"abc"
>
> [2]-""
>
> [3]-""
>
> [4]-"123"
>
> ...

Notice there are only 2 entries between "abc" and "123" though there are 3 delimiters.

NOTE: I've tried this with string.split and regex.split methods with the same results.

How can I go about making sure that regardless of the number of sequential delimiters, I get an array entry for each. (3 entries between "abc" and "123")

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

1. I understand that this is expected behavior.
2. If more information on the matter could be given, more might understand why the input should not be changed.
3. My "expectation" for a workaround/answer to this... probably going to have to be an extension method hand built. Just wanted to see if anyone had solved this problem and already built this wheel.

UPDATE2: The tilde in this scenario represents either a delimiter of fields OR an empty value that was never placed into the string. ~a~b would be simply a delimiter between a and b, but ~a~~~c represents a delimiter, empty value, delimiter c

UPDATE3:

~~~ represents a~~~c       in the array [a][""][c]
~ represents a~b    in the array [a][b]
only 1 and multiples of 3 tilde appear between valid inputs

a~~~~~~~~~b should equate to [a][""][""][""][b]

Comment: Because between 2 entries are three delimeters, if you had ~abc~x~y~123, there are three ~ there but only two entries, so you get two entries x and y, since yours are blank, you get two empty ones. Under no circumstance should you get three...

Comment: No, not the tilde itself but an empty entry in the array at 0 index. And yes, I know that this is expected behavior. I'd like to know how to change it.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what output you are expecting for that input, and why. Is it perhaps that each `~` is supposed to represent an empty entity, which we might possibly encounter more typically as `...,~,...`?

Comment: yes, each tilde represents either a REAL delimiter, or a placeholder of a value that was not received.

Comment: So would going from `input = "~abc~~~123~~~hijkl~9"` to `intermediate = ",abc,,,,123,,,,hijkl,,9"` help?

Comment: The tilde cannot be both a delimiter and an placeholder - pick a different delimiter or placeholder. | makes a good delimiter.

Comment: @rheitzman Changing the character will not change the problem.

Comment: If you use the same character as a delimiter, or occasionally as a placeholder, you do not have a valid delimiter. Or rather you occasionally have a valid delimiter. You just have bad data.

Comment: @rheitzman I don't disagree, but as I've stated many times in this thread... this wasn't my idea, I'm not in control of changing the design, I'm just the sap that gets to deal with it

Comment: Could you replace occurrences of ~~~ with ~(na)~?

Comment: Simple replace won't work as in previous comment. FYI the Update three second case appears to be wrong - there should be four empty fields not three. If the second case is correct you have bad data that I doubt anyone could repair. In may help if you post some real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** This answer only addresses the parts of the question preceding its "update" paragraph, because it was written before the question was edited.</sup>

`string.Split` will produce *n-1* empty parts for *n* consecutive separator characters. Since you want it to produce *n* empty parts instead, you are one tilde short wherever several of them occur consequtively. Add the "missing" tildes as follows before you perform the `Split`:

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

const string input = "~abc~~~123~~~hijkl~9";
string[] parts = Regex.Replace(input, "~~+", "$0~").Split('~');
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The rest of the string potentially consists of any number of tildes... so this wouldn't work... ~abc~~~~~~123~~k~h~~~~~~~~~~~~~~k

Comment: This was the workaround I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @MegaMark what's supposed to happen with the single `~` between the `l` and the `9` at the end of your original input string?

Comment: that is a plain delimiter, I would expect to have an empty string in the array at this spot due to the way I need to handle this parsing.... wait....

Comment: @MegaMark Wait, a "plain delimiter" would yield no empty string there, so is it a plain delimiter or is it a marker for an empty element which should be handled with a pair of commas?  Also, please @-tag people you're replying to in comments, so we see your replies.

Comment: Again, I didn't design this, I'm left with the fallout. There is no me changing the string, only me indexing what comes in by tilde. Not my choice, or design, just my problem

Comment: @stakx This was ALMOST the answer.... but it led me to what I needed. Any three consecutive ~~~ need to be treated as ~""~, all single ~ are just delimiters

Comment: Be sure to test with all fields containing a placeholder. How many fields are expected?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I've written [another somewhat more helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859201/240733) that should do what you want.

---

`string.Split` *by itself* is not appropriate to solve your issue, because this is how it works:

- Let's say you split the string `"A,B"` with `','` as the separator. You will get the parts `"A"` and `"B"`. **One separator character, zero empty parts.**
- Now let's split `"A,,B"`, again with `','` as the separator. You will get the parts `"A"`, `""`, and `"B"`. **Two separator characters, one empty part.**
- Then let's split `"A,,,B"`, again with `','` as the separator. You will get the parts `"A"`, `""`, `""`, and `"B"`. **Three separator characters, two empty parts.**
- The general rule is: ***n* consequtive separator characters produce *n-1* empty parts.**

Perhaps now you can see why `~~~` produces only two empty parts, not three.

(If you're willing to use string methods other than `string.Split`, then admittedly my answer is not very helpful.)

Comment: Sure, I see why, I understand why... I'm asking for a way to change/work around it.

Comment: Change your input string. `string.Split` works correctly. Your expectation of three empty parts for three `~` is wrong. Or use something other than `string.Split` if you don't want its behavior.

Comment: The input string cannot be changed. (no, not a design flaw on my part)

Comment: @MegaMark: Strings cannot be changed, but new strings can be derived from existing ones. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29859201/240733).

Answer (score 0):

From: [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If two delimiters are adjacent, or a delimiter is found at the
>   beginning or end of this instance, the corresponding array element
>   contains Empty.

Regarding this, `Split` method works as expected and the result you are currently getting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Amnon Shocot...

```
        string input = "~abc~~~123~~~hijkl~9";
        var postSplit = input.Split(new char[] {'~'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var postSplit2 = input.Split('~').Where(ss => ss != String.Empty);
```

with regurlar expressions, unfortunately we still need to filter out empty strings, because of the first match.

```
        Regex rr = new Regex("~+"); // you may have been missing the +
        var postSplit3 = rr.Split(input).Where(ss => ss != String.Empty);
```

Comment: I want the string.empty fields in the array.

Answer (score -1):

In vb:

```
    Dim input As String = "~abc~~~123~~~hijkl~9"
    Dim post() As String = input.Split({"~"c}, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Looks like #3 has the remainder including the ~9

---

```
    Dim input As String = "~abc~~~123~~~hijkl~9".Replace("~~~", "~na~")
    If input.StartsWith("~") Then input = "na" & input
    If input.EndsWith("~~") Then input &= "~na"
    Dim post() As String = input.Split({"~"c})
```

This works on the sample string but if adjacent fields contain a placeholder it will get more complicated. you may have to iterate over the string making on replacement at a time until the string length doesn't change.

Comment: This is the opposite behavior of what I'm looking for

Comment: OK. How many fields are you expecting? input.Split({"~"c}) yields 9 which appears to be correct.